# Representing float values in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

Look at the three lines of code below.

```
  float f = 1;

  float g = 1.1;

  float h = 1.1f;
```

Second line has compilation errors, while the other lines do not have compilation errors. First line is working fine without suffix f and third line is working with suffix f. Why is this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Floating point literals in Java is a `double` value by default.

> #### [JLS 3.10.2 Floating-Point Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.2)
>
> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d`.

You can't assign a `double` value to a `float` without an explicit narrowing conversion. You therefore have two options:

- For literals, use the suffix `f` or `F` to denote a `float` value
- For non-literals, use an explicit cast `(float)`

An example of the latter is:

```
double d = 1.1;
float f = (float) d; // compiles fine!
```

---

#### On widening conversions

The reason why this compiles:

```
float f = 1;
```

is because the widening conversion from `int` to `float` can be done implicitly in the context of an assignment.

> #### [JLS 5.2 Assignment Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2)
>
> *Assignment conversion* occurs when the value of an expression is assigned to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable. Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - [...]
>
> #### [JLS 5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2)
>
> The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the *widening primitive conversions*:
>
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - [...]

---

#### Other data type suffix for literals

As mentioned above, there's also the `D` or `d` suffix for `double`. Consider this snippet for example:

```
static void f(int i) {
    System.out.println("(int)");
}
static void f(double d) {
    System.out.println("(double)");
}

//...
f(1);   // prints "(int)"
f(1D);  // prints "(double)"
```

There's also a suffix for `long` literals, which is `L` or `l` (lowercase letter). It is *highly recommended* that you use the uppercase variant.

> #### [JLS 3.10.1 Integer Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1)
>
> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (`ell`); otherwise it is of type `int`. The suffix `L` is preferred, because the letter `l` (`ell`) is often hard to distinguish from the digit `1` (`one`).

Answer (score 7):

You're assigning a `double` value to a `float` variable.  `1.1` by itself (without the `f` tacked on the end) is assumed by the compiler to be of type `double`.  The compiler doesn't like to make implicit downcasts because there's potential there to lose precision.

Comment: (To be more explicit - floating-point constants in Java are `double` by default, unless they include the `f` on the end which makes them `float`.)

Answer (score 1):

First line automatically casts `int` to `float` (ok).

Second line could not cast `double` to `float` because of loss of precision. You can make an explicit cast:

```
float g = (float) 1.1;
```

Third line does not need modification.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, every floating-point number (any number with a decimal point) defaults to a `double`, which is more precise than a `float`.  And by default, Java does not let you convert a `double` to a `float` because of the loss of precision.

You can still assign a `double` to a `float` by casting:

```
float g = (float) 1.1;
```