# Converting a double to float

Tags: java, class, double

```
    class calc_Payroll

    private float hours;
    private float rate;
    private int hrsStr;
    float gross;

    calc_Payroll(float a, float b, float c, float d)
    {
    gross = hours + (hrsStr * 1.33) * rate;  //error here
    }
```

I'm confused as to where I have converted anything to a double? but the error I am getting is

cannot covert double to float

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369726/declaring-floats-why-default-type-double

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033137/representing-float-values-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102955/java-why-do-you-need-to-specify-a-f-in-a-float-literal

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369726/declaring-floats-why-default-type-double

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that question.

Answer (score 4):

`1.33` is a `double` literal, and it causes the entire `hours + (hrsStr * 1.33) * rate` expression to return a `double` value, which can't be assigned to a `float` variable without an explicit cast.

Change it to `1.33f` for a `float` literal.